# How to evaulate $\int \cos x \sqrt{5 + \cos^2 x} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I evaluate
$$
\int \cos x \sqrt{5 + \cos^2 x} dx?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int\cos x\sqrt{5+\cos^2x}dx=\int\cos x\sqrt{6-\sin^2x}dx$$

Now put $\sin x=u$ and use Point $\#8$ of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ13/integ13.html) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29163/integral-int-sqrt25-x2dx)